# examine the result of groupBy followed by orderBy in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe, including two columns, e.g., `"ID"` and `"Time"`. I would like to quickly check the result of grouped by ID and based on the time information.

I can do this

```
df.groupBy('ID').orderBy('Time')
```

But I cannot add show after that because `show()` is not a attribute of either orderBy or groupBy. How to quickly check this kind of operation result.

Comment: without an aggregation, group by is meaningless. You probably just wanted to sort by ID?

Comment: Adding to @mck's question above, when you were saying  "check the result of grouped by ID", what exactly do you want to check?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick check (and if you do not care too much about performance) you can use [GroupedData.applyInPandas()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) to print out each group separately as Pandas Dataframe:

```python
def debug(pandas_df):
    print(pandas_df.sort_values("Time"))
    return pandas_df

df = df.groupBy("ID").applyInPandas(lambda pandas_df: debug(pandas_df), df.schema)
df.<call action>()
```

In a multi node environment, the debug messages will be printed out on the executors.